# Import SQL statements from another SQL script

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have an SQL script that does a bunch of stuff to some existing tables in my DB, but part of that scripts need to operate with data present on a non-existing table in order to update some values.

That table is only temporary; I have an .sql file that contains:

- CREATE TABLE big_table
- POPULATION of that same big_table

So the idea is, my SQL script contains the import of that .sql file, that should execute it (it will create the big_table in my DB and populate it), then my already existing script will execute all it's operations and then I'll just run a DROP TABLE big_table since I'll no longer need it.

Being an POSTGRESQL DDBB, I've thought about:

> db_name < file.sql

, also:

> mysql -u username -p db_name < file.sql

, but that I cannot include into an SQL script, I can only run that trough a shell which is not the idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "DDBB"? If you mean "database" then the abbreviation is just "Db".

Comment: If you are using `psql` you can use `\i` to include on SQL script from another.

Comment: Why would you use mysql to connect to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.